# Is it possible to filter a TextInput value before the entered characters are shown?

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput that should only accept numeric values. I can more or less force this by using keyboardType "number-pad" on iOS, but Android only has "numeric", which provides keys for characters like `-` or `,`. Even then, an attached hardware keyboard (like the iOS Simulator / Android Emulator have by default) still allows entry of non-numeric characters.

Everything I can find online is filtering the entered value in onChangeText, storing the filtered value in the state and use the state as the TextInputs value – while this does work, it causes the entered value to briefly appear before the JavaScript is able to filter it. Since I can't force the Android keyboard to only show numbers, I really want to avoid this visual behavior.

Android has [android:digits](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits) for this, but I don't think this is available in React Native.

Is there any way to filter the TextInputs value before it is displayed?

Comment: Can you post the code snippet of how you are handling it?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think solution for now is to accepts extra characters on Android and when you are submitting the form just transform that text field's input before sending to server :)